# Add new Column to existing Dataview

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to add New Column to the Existing Dataview  as shown in below image. the new column should have value 1 or 0 base upon the value of DocumentType,HouseOrigin and StorageDate. basically i am checking if Document type and HouseOrigin  is same then put 0 for the latest storageDate and put 1 for other row.

Hope below image will help to understand.

[image]

How i will do it ? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am get it. Hope that helps !!

```
  If DetailsView.Count > 0 Then

            Dim col As DataColumn = New DataColumn("DisableFlag", GetType(Boolean))
            col.DefaultValue = True

            DetailsView.Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DisableFlag", GetType(Boolean)))

            Dim LocalDV As DataView = DetailsView
            Dim result As List(Of DataTable) = DetailsView.Table.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("DocumentType")).[Select](Function(g) g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList()

            For Each rowView As DataRowView In DetailsView
                Dim row As DataRow = rowView.Row

                For Each DivByDocTypedt As DataTable In result
                    Dim maxDate As Object = DivByDocTypedt.Compute("MAX(StorageDate)", Nothing)

                    For Each DivByDocTyperow As DataRow In DivByDocTypedt.Rows
                        If (DivByDocTyperow.Item("Guid") = row.Item("Guid")) Then
                            If (maxDate = row.Item("StorageDate")) Then
                                row.SetField("DisableFlag", False)
                            Else
                                row.SetField("DisableFlag", True)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next '' DivByDocTyperow
                Next ''DivByDocTypedt
            Next ''rowView of DetailsView
```